# Dart list is null after initialization

Tags: flutter, oop, asynchronous, dart, nullpointerexception

**I am very new at Dart so if this problem seems trivial or not required, I apologize!!**

Now, I have initialized a a `List<String>` variable in global scope and add values into it through another method in the same class:

```
// global variable
List<String> images = List(2);

getImages() async {
    // tried adding values but it is still null
    images[0] = ("https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b5/03/dd/b503dd2350f4b5c248a1f0909433fcfe.jpg");
    images[1] = ("https://i.pinimg.com/236x/04/80/ff/0480ff67b54dc03bb18da3d90e2c2a82.jpg");

    // get a Future<List<String> from another class
    List<String> items = await FirebaseStorage().getMoodBoardImages(); 
    print("items: " + items[0]); // returns a value


    print("images" + images[0]); // cause of error
    images.addAll(items);
    }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
E/flutter (28986): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(213)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (28986): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]=' was called on null.
E/flutter (28986): Receiver: null
E/flutter (28986): Tried calling: []=(0, "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b5/03/dd/b503dd2350f4b5c248a1f0909433fcfe.jpg")
E/flutter (28986): #0 Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (28986): #1 _ProfileState.getImages (package:calmante/screens/profile/profile.dart:334:11)
E/flutter (28986): #2 _ProfileState.build (package:calmante/screens/profile/profile.dart:30:5)
```

**EDIT:** The code below is partially correct because the exception is removed but I am not able to display the image url through Flutter

```
getImages() async {
    images = List(2); // Add this
    // tried adding values but it is still null
    images[0] = ("https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b5/03/dd/b503dd2350f4b5c248a1f0909433fcfe.jpg");
    images[1] = ("https://i.pinimg.com/236x/04/80/ff/0480ff67b54dc03bb18da3d90e2c2a82.jpg");

    // get a Future<List<String> from another class
    List<String> items = await FirebaseStorage().getMoodBoardImages(); 
    print("items: " + items[0]); // returns a value


    print("images" + images[0]); // cause of error
    images.addAll(items);
}
```

**EDIT:** SO I think the above code only changed where the exception was occurring because now it is triggered inside the build method.

**Code:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getImages();
    setPalette();

    print("images build: " + images[0]);
}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown building Profile(dirty, state: _ProfileState#71db6):
Invalid argument(s)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Profile file:///C:/Users/ugam.UG-GW-L163/AndroidStudioProjects/calmante/lib/screens/first.dart:19:5
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:262:57)
#1      _ProfileState.build (package:calmante/screens/profile/profile.dart:33:28)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
...
```

Comment: Obviously your `images` variables is not correctly initialized. Moreover, it appears that the error comes from `images[0]=` line. Can you please provide some more code ?

Comment: what code do you want? I am using flutter so, the `build` method or the firestore class from which I am getting the `list`

Comment: make sure that you don't set images somewhere else in your code. The code above would produce no error, unless you override images before using it with null.

Comment: `set images`

what do you mean by that?

Comment: please look at the code I have updated

Comment: Note that `getImages` is `async` which means that it may not complete immediately. In particular, it may not complete before the first `build` happens. In `build` you need to allow for some values being null. One common pattern is to return a progress indicator from build until the values are not null. BTW - you should not be calling `getImages` from `build`. You probably meant to call it from `initState`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, that may not suits your needs : re-initialize `images` on top of `getImages()` :

```dart
getImages() async {
    images = List(2); // Add this
    // tried adding values but it is still null
    images[0] = ("https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b5/03/dd/b503dd2350f4b5c248a1f0909433fcfe.jpg");
    images[1] = ("https://i.pinimg.com/236x/04/80/ff/0480ff67b54dc03bb18da3d90e2c2a82.jpg");

    // get a Future<List<String> from another class
    List<String> items = await FirebaseStorage().getMoodBoardImages(); 
    print("items: " + items[0]); // returns a value


    print("images" + images[0]); // cause of error
    images.addAll(items);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't show the exception but I am not able to display the image through the url with flutter, should I share my code?